# $(document).ready(function() outside head

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to move this script out of the head of my HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.emoticontext').emoticonize({
        });
    })
</script>
```

I would like insert it into a .js file.

like

```
<script src="javascripts/emoticons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but I'm not sure how I can do it.

I tried

```
(function($) {

    $('.emoticontext').emoticonize({ 
        });

    $.fn.emoticonize = function(options) {
    ...
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you put exactly what you have in your script element ?

Comment: I tried it before but dont work... now it works im not sure why... Thank you guys

Answer (score 4):

In your emoticons.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.emoticontext').emoticonize({
    });
});
```

Thats it.

This code

```
(function($) {
    $('.emoticontext').emoticonize({ 
    });

    $.fn.emoticonize = function(options) {
    ...
```

Creates a prototype function called emoticonize, that is designed to be called on a jQuery element.

Answer (score 1):

Simply . . .

Put this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.emoticontext').emoticonize({
    });
 })
```

In your external file and link to it . . .
In other words, everything in your in page js between the  tags

Answer (score 0):

When moving this JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.emoticontext').emoticonize({
    });
})
```

from a `<script>` element into its own file, it will look exactly the same.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.emoticontext').emoticonize({
        });
    })

    $.fn.emoticonize = function(options) {
        …
```

As a matter of good practice, though, I’d put it *after* the definition of `emoticonize` – just in case the script gets deferred/asynchronously loaded in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Several things: first you just strip out the script tags, leaving it the exact same. The other thing is that you are missing the semicolon from the closing }). It should be });.

Also, don't forget to link to jQuery in your head tag.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**emoticons.js**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.emoticontext').emoticonize({
    });
})
```